# Fastlane upload dSYMS from folder

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I have a Fastlane lane to download and upload dSYMS to Crashlytics:

```
download_dsyms
upload_symbols_to_crashlytics
```

I messed up and because of that the `download_dsyms` action isn't working for my latest build on the App Store. I've managed to download the dSYMS from App Store Connect. Is there a way to pass the content of that folder I downloaded from App Store Connect to `upload_symbols_to_crashlytics`?